# MySQL views and authorization

Tags: mysql, view, authorization

I'm a little confused on how exactly views and authorizations work.  Let's say a view, view1, is created based only off table1, and a user is granted access to the original table1.  Would that user be able to have the same privileges to view1 as they would have on table1?  Also if a user is granted permission to update/insert/delete on view1, would that privilege be possible as they would also change the underlying table1?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The permissions are totally seperate, here is an example

```
create table table1
(
    blah int
)

create view view1 as
select * from table1
```

Having permission on table1 does not mean you have permissions on view1, and permissions on table1 are not required to be able to use view1. This is one of the uses of views, it allows you to easily grant access to only a subset of the data in a table.

Comment: Thank you! I have another question though. A user grants access to table1, who then creates view1.  Let's say I want to be able to revoke access to table1 as well as the privileges to view1 (which was based off table1), how can I do this?

Comment: `revoke select,insert,delete update on view1 from user1` should work fine. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/revoke.html